# Convert string to specific decimal format

Tags: c#

How can I convert a string that is always a length of 5 into a decimal point format as xx.xxx?

For example, a string "01000" to a decimal that is always in the format of 01.000?   I would actually like to be able to  any number for example "19999" to a decimal that is 19.999.

Comment: It is not clear if your desidered result should be another string with the decimal separator or a proper decimal value

Comment: Convert to decimal and divide by 1000...

Comment: @DavidG well, except for rounding errors and the fact that there are no leading zeros for numbers => he wants a string, not a decimal.

Comment: @Steve It is. He wants the result to be 01.000 which is only possible if this is a string. Numbers can't have leading zeros.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Actually OP doesn't specify if they want string or decmial, question is unclear and should be closed imo.

Comment: @DavidG He wants the result to be 01.000. Please show me how you do that with numbers instead of strings.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar That's why I said it's unclear.

Comment: @DavidG And that's why I say it is not - there's no other way to do it than with strings :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Other than using decimals and setting a display format in the UI...

Comment: @DavidG What if there is no UI and this is simply a command line tool parsing some input generating some output?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar which reinforces my point that it's unclear :)

Comment: @DavidG No, it enforces my point that from what the question says, the solution is pretty clear: It can only be a string, and a decimal point can statically be inserted :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Well at least neither of us suggested Linq :)

Comment: @DavidG Hehehe, yep. When the only tool you know is a hammer...

Comment: I will be converting the string to a proper decimal value after the decimal point is inserted into the string. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Oooh, looks like I was right! :)

Comment: @davidg oh well...

Comment: Then your requirement makes no sense. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

If your requirements are correct (always 5 digits, always seperating after the second digit) you can simply do

```
input = "01000"; // or "19999"
var result = input.Insert(2, "."); // "01.000" or "19.999"
```

No need for parsing or substrings.

---

If your question actually was not about string represention, but you want to convert the string `"01000"` to a `double` with value `1.0` (or `19.999` from `"19999"`) you can simply parse the string like that:

```
double d = double.Parse(input);
// to represent it as the desired string again use
string output = d.ToString("00.000");
```

Comment: D'oh!  I didn't think of that! Grr! :)

Comment: You beat me by 54 seconds :(

Comment: one can see this is a smart solution by all these fast upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

`decimal myDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal("01000") / 1000;`

This will work providing the string input and the output format are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

It will have to stay a string, not a decimal.  You can't control where the decimal point goes and you can't have leading zeroes if you convert it to an actual `decimal` type.  For example, if you convert `01000` to a `decimal` with `01.000` it will be `1.0`.

Use this: `input.substring(0, 2) + "." + input.substring(2);`

Comment: That is not a decimal, isn't it?

Comment: Once you convert it, the decimal point will go where it wants.  It has to stay a string.

Comment: @UweKeim The OP said a _decialm point format_ so it's not clear if they just want to insert a decimal or actually parse the `string` to a `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the result to be a string as well, one solution could be to simply insert the decimal point:

```
var newString = String.Format("{0}.{1}", input.Substring(0, 2), input.SubString(2));
```

or

```
var newString = input.Insert(2, ".");
```

Otherwise your requirement doesn't make sense, as a numeric value can not have leading zeros (or trailing ones after the decimal point for that matter). They are just a number.

---

According to the comment to your question this requirement doesn't make sense. Instead, perform a proper division.

```
var dec = Decimal.Parse(s);
var value = dec / 1000.0m;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but you can do it also by using Linq:

```
var x = String.Concat(
            input.Select(
                (c, i) => (i == 2) ? '.' + c.ToString() : c.ToString()
            )
        );
```

Comment: This is the craziest way to do this! Why would you even consider Linq for some basic string manipulation?

Comment: I guess you could also take a screen shot, print that, use a pen to paint a decimal dot in the right place, OCR it and then use Office Interop to get the resulting string from the word document. Seriously. LINQ is a nice thing, but it's not always the answer.

Comment: You could also make an API that inserts decimal points that you install into MS Azure that passes the values over a service bus and outputs the value back to another API that is provided by a company that prints the value to a postcard and sends it back to the user. That would be stupid too...

Comment: The possibilities are endless! And all this new electro-stuff provides much more elegant ways of shooting your foot than the old wooden table (http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Web_0_0x2e_1).

Comment: "Scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, that they didn't stop to think of whether or not they should." - Ian Malcolm

Comment: well, let's assume we are forced to do this operation in plain C with pointers, where we dont have the String.Insert method. You would have to implement a basic for-loop exactly like in this Linq expression, with the difference that you can manipulate the string in place with realloc and you dont  need the Concat part. Since it is clear that the user who asks this question is a beginner, i dont see any problem with my answer except that it can wide his horizon. In a real world application I would also use the Insert() method.

Comment: The problem with your answer is the fact that even I (and I consider myself an experienced developer) had to really think about your solution. How can you assume that a beginner would understand the above?

Comment: @DrewKennedy -- Oh yes!!  You did!  You pulled out the apropos Ian Malcolm quote!!  We have a T-Rex!